# Form.ShowDialog() or Form.ShowDialog(this)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I heard that if I call form.ShowDialog() without specifying the owner, then there can be a case when I will not see the dialog form on screen (it will be hidden with other windows). Is it true? I used ShowDialog() without specifying the owner hundreds of times and I never had any problems with that.

Can you please explain in which situation I could get the described problem?

**UPDATE:**

Well, I did many experiments and I couldn't get any real unexpected problems with using ShowDialog() (without specifying the owner).

So I think it's just rumors that ShowDialog() can lead to problems.
If you don't agree - give me a code sample please that leads to a problem.

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply in winforms, but for the record, I came here because I was having problems in WPF. If I switched to another application, when I clicked again on the parent form, the child dialog got stuck behind (bummer as the child dialog was set to not show in taskbar).

Setting the owner of the dialog fixed this problem.

Comment: Start a background worker and call ShowDialog. The window won't show up in front of your application but on the background (just to annoy us programmers this only happens every now and then).

Comment: Barfieldmv, I tried to do what you have suggested and the form appears on top, not on the background.

Comment: *give me a code sample please that leads to a problem* - wrong approach. The contract is MSDN, implementation behavior is the mood of today. Behavior may be differen on a different version of Windows, and can change with Windows update, Windows features, or other programs. A modal window does have an owner, everyone else expects you to specify the correct one.

Comment: As for an example: `Form1` with a button that starts a timer of ~1s. The timer's `Tick` event stops the timer, and opens `Form2` with `ShowDialog`. Set `Form2.ShowInTaskbar=false`so it behaves like a popup. Start the program, click the button, then select another program *before* the timer fires. Click the Taskbar icon to bring your app in the foreground again. On my system, I observe: The disabled Form1 gets input focus (instead of Form2), and clicking Form1 doesn't blink Form2's title bar.

Comment: @peterchen: then why the contract with the dialog allows us to do the wrong thing and not specify it?

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia: I'm didn't design the WInforms API, but from my experience: it might be OK *some* of the time, or it seemed like a good idea back then.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just to better understand the owner-owned relationship:

> .NET allows a form to “own” other forms. Owned forms are useful for
>   floating toolbox and command windows. One example of an owned form is
>   the Find and Replace window in Microsoft Word. When an owner window is
>   minimized, the owned forms are also minimized automatically. When an
>   owned form overlaps its owner, it is always displayed on top.

(c) "Pro .NET 2.0 Windows Forms and Custom Controls" by Matthew MacDonald.

---

> As **ShowDialog** shows the new form, an **implicit relationship is
>   established** between the currently active form, known as the owner
>   form, and the new form, known as the owned form. This relationship
>   ensures that the owned form is the active form and is always shown on
>   top of the owner form.
>
> One feature of this relationship is that the owned form affects the
>   behavior of its owner form (when using **ShowDialog**):
>
> - The owner form cannot be minimized, maximized, or even moved.
> - The owned form blocks mouse and keyboard input to the owner form.
> - The owner form is minimized when the owned form is.
> - Only the owned form can be closed.
> - If both owner and owned forms are minimized and if the user presses Alt+Tab to switch to the owned form, the owned form is activated.
>
> Unlike the ShowDialog method, however, a call to the **Show** method **does
>   not establish an implicit owner-owned relationship**. This means that
>   either form can be the currently active form.
>
> Without an implicit owner-owned relationship, owner and owned forms
>   alike can be minimized, maximized, or moved. If the user closes any
>   form other than the main form, the most recently active form is
>   reactivated.
>
> Although **ShowDialog establishes an implicit owner-owned relationship**,
>   there is no built-in way for the owned form to call back to or query
>   the form that opened it. In the modeless case, you can set the new
>   form's Owner property to establish the owner-owned relationship. As a
>   shortcut, you could pass the owner form as an argument to an overload
>   of the Show method, which also takes an IWin32Window parameter
>   (IWin32Window is implemented by Windows Forms UI objects that expose a
>   Win32 HWND property via the IWin32Window.Handle property).
>
> The behavior of forms in an explicit modal owner-owned form
>   relationship is the same as its implicit modal counterpart, but the
>   modeless owner-owned relationship provides additional behavior in the
>   non-owner-owned modeless case. First, the modeless owned form always
>   appears on top of the owner form, even though either can be active.
>   This is useful when you need to keep a form, such as a floating tool
>   window, on top of other forms within an application. Second, if the
>   user presses Alt+Tab to switch from the owner, the owned forms follow
>   suit. To ensure that the user knows which form is the main form,
>   minimizing the owner hides the task bar buttons for all owned forms,
>   leaving only the owner's task bar button visible.

(c) "Windows Forms 2.0 Programming" by Chris Sells, Michael Weinhardt.

Comment: Life saver, now i can do what i need

Comment: Wonderful detailed answer!

Comment: For instance if you launch a ShowDialog from a separate thread, the is no way to know who own the new Window, so you can specify it.

Comment: Can we get save file dialog (Already opened) in a control, like we get the forms using Application.OpenForms ?

Answer (score 26):

One annoyance I found with `ShowDialog()` vs `ShowDialog(this)`.

Run the TestApp, show the `newform.ShowDialog()`, click "show Desktop" on your taskbar or Quick launch toolbar, click on the TestApp on the taskbar. It shows the Mainform. You have to do an Alt-Tab to get to your newform.

VS

Run the TestApp, show the `newform.ShowDialog(this)`, click "show Desktop" on your taskbar or Quick launch toolbar, click on the TestApp on the taskbar. It shows the newform on top.

Comment: I am having the exact the problem you describe. But I have changed ShowDialog() to ShowDialog(this) and it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 10):

"Currently active Window" usually refers to the foreground window, but only if it belongs to the current thread - see [GetActiveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646292(VS.85).aspx) in MSDN.

(The actual information is in the community content, but the commenter is right that there is no "per-thread active window", AFAIK).

So when the user switched to another applications (or threads) window, you end up with some "default window". Even if .NET does some magic here, the modality will be broken: the intended parent window does not get disabled (e.g. you could switch to your main window, and close it, or modify something, which often breaks your application due to reentrancy).

Also, if another application is currently active, your dialog will not be shown on top, but it will be hidden behind some other window.

As a minor annoyance, the initial position is usually incorrect or misleading.

In practive, this happens rarely, though: if you open the dialog in response to a menu or button click on your main window, the user doesn't will virtually never manage to switch to another window.

However, it is technically possible, and quite likely to happen if you open the dialog in response to some automation, external message etc.

Comment: As a general rule, if it's possible to specify the parent, the parent should be specified.  It never hurts, and it frequently helps.

Comment: I actually have this problem - I am running an external process from an outlook plugin - and it doesn't show the dialog. Any ideas how to show the dialog ? It doesn't have any form -> i just want to show a dialog. If I call "MessageBox.Show" before - it works - otherwise not.

Comment: @bernhardrusch: Did you try specifying the .NET equivalent of GetDesktopWindow as parent?

Answer (score 7):

The parameterless ShowDialog() simply uses a "default" parent. 
For what it's worth, the default parent is whatever the "currently active window" is. When you care what the parent is, you need to set it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, but I know that ShowDialog() uses a currently active window, I just don't know how there can be a situation that dialog will appear the way the user will not be able to see it.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was to call `ShowDialog()` from a form that was brought up with `ShowDialog()`. The result was a hidden form with no way to access it to close it.

After reading this topic, I tried `ShowDialog(this)` and it worked perfectly. The second dialog showed on top, centered, and completely functional. When the second form was set to `Dialogresult.OK` it allowed access to the underlying dialog which was able read its properties and then close it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does make difference in some cases. I had no problem with parameterless method until now, and I was a bit surprised that the parent form was not the default form. So, to avoid unexpected behavior, always pass the real parent form to ShowDialog method.

Answer (score 1):

Take the following example:

In your main form, you have a ListView, with label editing enabled. When a specific label is edited, you launch a second window, (using `ShowDialog()` in `AfterLabelEdit`). The new form doesn't show in the task bar.

If your user starts editing the label, then clicks on another application, then the second form will show, but when returning to your application the user will only be presented with your main form, disabled since a modal dialog is showing. Yet, the usual blinking mechanism (which brings the modal dialog to font if you click the caller) will not work (surely because the AfterEdit call has not returned yet), and your user will not be able to reach the second form except by cycling through open windows using Ctrl+Tab.

Calling `ShowDialog(this)` fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and to solve it change the windows state property to normal, because maybe its minimized.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, 1709 and .NET 4.0 I don't see this taskbar scenario you detail.  Maybe this was fixed / tweaked after you initially posted this.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a case where not specifying the owner using `this` caused a serious problem.

Upon launch my application forces itself to go fullscreen and also makes sure it always has focus, even if the user tries to Alt+Tab out of it, unless you log in as an administrator or developer.

When I use `ShowDialog()` on a custom form the dialog box appears *behind* my application for some reason, and the application itself becomes unresponsive because the dialog box is currently active. If I use `ShowDialog(this)` then the form shows up as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I found another case where using `ShowDialog()` without specify an owner can cause problems. That problem brought me here.

When you have a form that auto-closes (like an loading indicator) that was shown just before the modal form.

In this case, when the loading form closes, it will also close the modal form, as described by @nightcoder [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17392897/7335274).

consider the following example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();

        // Config Form2 to close automatically after 2 seconds
        var timer2 = new Timer();
        timer2.Start();
        timer2.Interval = 2000;
        timer2.Tick += (s, ev) =>
        {
            form2.Close();
        };
        form2.Show();

        var form3 = new Form3();

        // When Form2 closes, it will close Form3 too, because Form2 owns Form3
        // The currently active window (Form2) is made the owner of Form3
        // form3.ShowDialog();

        // Here, Form1 owns Form3, so when Form2 closes, it does not close Form3
        form3.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps someone