# Windows forms: ShowDialog - dialog doesn't show up

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, modal-dialog

I am running an external process from an outlook plugin - and it doesn't show the dialog. I am using ShowDialog without parameters.

Any ideas how to show the dialog ?

The process doesn't have any form - i just want to show a dialog with some selections. If I call "MessageBox.Show" before, the dialog is shown - otherwise not.

I guess it is something like the answer of Peterchen in this thread: [Form.ShowDialog() or Form.ShowDialog(this)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816885/form-showdialog-or-form-showdialogthis/817240#817240)

BTW I don't have any owner, because this process doesn't have any "main window".

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need a parent window for modal windows to work. After all, the only difference from Show() is that the child window blocks the parent. You can always create a hidden dummy window and use it as a main window but why not just use .Show() since it works ?

Comment: it has to be asynchron and should block the application until the user selected something -> this is much easier this way.

Comment: well - I've created a dummy window and used it as an owner - now it works