# What's difference between ShowDialog() and ShowDialog(IWin32Window) in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Both `ShowDialog();` and `ShowDialog(IWin32Window);` seem to do the exact same thing to me. The documentation isn't very clear either.

I've been told that `ShowDialog(IWin32Window);` will ensure that the dialog window is on top of the whatever is passed in as the owner window.

The MSDN documenation makes no mention of this, so it feels like a bit of black magic.

Comment: @XTG When editing a post the 'comment' field is for putting down what you edited in the post. Please do not put *"edited by xtg"*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx makes it pretty clear that the parameter represents the owner window.  And that is the behavior of an owner window - it stays behind its children and doesn't close leaving its children still displayed.

Comment: The piece I was missing was that ShowDialog() will make the current active window the parent. In MOST cases, this will cause ShowDialog() and ShowDialog(IWin32Window) to behave identically, at least to the user. But if you've got a ton of windows open, and are running background process on multiple threads and invoking them back to the UI thread, you can get some really interesting behavior.

Comment: Helper for using WinForms ShowDialog with WPF windows: http://www.ticklishtechs.net/2009/12/22/how-to-get-a-iwin32window-from-a-wpf-window/

Answer (score 5):

When ShowDialog() is called, the currently active window is made the owner of the dialog box. If you want to specify a specific owner, use the other version of this method (ShowDialog(IWin32Window)).

This is stated in the MSDN documenation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx

Comment: And if the owner (last active form) is closed, it will also close the modal form. Sometimes it is difficult to know which form was the last active one; it could be a loading indicator that shows just before the modal form. So, it's better to specify the owner using ShowDialog(IWin32Window). You can see a sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76493929/7335274)

Answer (score 3):

Internally `ShowDialog()` calls `ShowDialog(IWin32Window)` with a null argument.  If the argument is not null, it is set as the form's owner.  If owner is null, it will use `GetActiveWindow()` to get a `IntPtr` to the active window and use this as the owner.  You can check it out yourself using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).

Answer (score 1):

> .NET allows a form to “own” other forms. Owned forms are useful for
>   floating toolbox and command windows. One example of an owned form is
>   the Find and Replace window in Microsoft Word. When an owner window is
>   minimized, the owned forms are also minimized automatically. When an
>   owned form overlaps its owner, it is always displayed on top.

(c) "Pro .NET 2.0 Windows Forms and Custom Controls" by Matthew MacDonald.

---

> As **ShowDialog** shows the new form, an **implicit relationship is
>   established** between the currently active form, known as the owner
>   form, and the new form, known as the owned form. This relationship
>   ensures that the owned form is the active form and is always shown on
>   top of the owner form.
>
> One feature of this relationship is that the owned form affects the
>   behavior of its owner form (when using **ShowDialog**):
>
> - The owner form cannot be minimized, maximized, or even moved.
> - The owned form blocks mouse and keyboard input to the owner form.
> - The owner form is minimized when the owned form is.
> - Only the owned form can be closed.
> - If both owner and owned forms are minimized and if the user presses Alt+Tab to switch to the owned form, the owned form is activated.
>
> Unlike the ShowDialog method, however, a call to the **Show** method **does
>   not establish an implicit owner-owned relationship**. This means that
>   either form can be the currently active form.
>
> Without an implicit owner-owned relationship, owner and owned forms
>   alike can be minimized, maximized, or moved. If the user closes any
>   form other than the main form, the most recently active form is
>   reactivated.
>
> Although **ShowDialog establishes an implicit owner-owned relationship**,
>   there is no built-in way for the owned form to call back to or query
>   the form that opened it. In the modeless case, you can set the new
>   form's Owner property to establish the owner-owned relationship. As a
>   shortcut, you could pass the owner form as an argument to an overload
>   of the Show method, which also takes an IWin32Window parameter
>   (IWin32Window is implemented by Windows Forms UI objects that expose a
>   Win32 HWND property via the IWin32Window.Handle property).
>
> The behavior of forms in an explicit modal owner-owned form
>   relationship is the same as its implicit modal counterpart, but the
>   modeless owner-owned relationship provides additional behavior in the
>   non-owner-owned modeless case. First, the modeless owned form always
>   appears on top of the owner form, even though either can be active.
>   This is useful when you need to keep a form, such as a floating tool
>   window, on top of other forms within an application. Second, if the
>   user presses Alt+Tab to switch from the owner, the owned forms follow
>   suit. To ensure that the user knows which form is the main form,
>   minimizing the owner hides the task bar buttons for all owned forms,
>   leaving only the owner's task bar button visible.

(c) "Windows Forms 2.0 Programming" by Chris Sells, Michael Weinhardt.

Answer (score 0):

frm2.ShowDialog() make frm2 as a model dialog box, we can not click anywhere on form1 unless we close the instance of frm2.

frm2.show() there is no such restriction.