# FormClosing Event Firing before I call Me.Close

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, modal-dialog

I have a form (`frmMain`) that opens up another form (`frmEdit`) modally.

This in turn opens up a third form (`frmSelection`) modally.

My problem is that when `frmSelection` is closed, `frmEdit` also closes, yet nothing is actually closing it in my code.

Note the `FormClosing` and `FormClosed` events fire in the `frmEdit`

The code in `frmMain`

```
Using edit as New frmEdit
    edit.ShowDialog
End Using
```

The code in `frmEdit`:

```
Private Sub btnEditSelectionCriteria_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEditSelectionCriteria.Click
    Using sel As New frmSelection
        sel.ShowDialog
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    Me.Close ' this is not called (breakpoint is not hit)
End Sub

Private Sub frmEditTask_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    'This fires when OK button clicked in frmSelection
End Sub
```

The code in `frmSelection`:

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    Me.Close ' this causes the FormClosing event to fire in frmEdit
End Sub
```

How can I track down what is closing my form? I thought there may be an exception being thrown but I checked Thrown in Common Language Runtime Exceptions to no avail.

Comment: In a quick test I'm unable to reproduce your symptoms.  On a side note, though, instead of `Me.Close` you should set DialogResult with something like: `Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK`

Comment: Did you specify the owner of frmSelection as frmEdit? http://stackoverflow.com/q/816885/2258

Comment: @RichardMorgan - that doesn't have any effect

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of this head scratcher - thanks to @Idle_Mind for the pointer:-

My button `btnEditSelectionCriteria` had the `DialogResult` property set to `Cancel`

This is actually a gotcha. If you create a button on a form then set the `CancelButton` property of the Form to be this button, it changes the `DialogResult` property of that button to `Cancel`.

This is what I had done, then I copied and pasted the cancel button to `btnEditSelectionCriteria` and this had retained the `DialogResult` property of `Cancel`