# Form hides behind the other form after ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, visual-studio, messagebox

I have used a customized `Messagebox` in my application that inherits from the `Form` class. It works fine when I use it on my main form. But when I use its `Show()` function on a form that is itself popped up from the main form, the `Messagebox` hides under the second form and the program therefore becomes unavailable.

Even when I use its `BringToFront()` function before `ShowDialog()` it still goes back.
This is the `Show()` function of this customized Messagebox. I can share more of its code if necessary:

```
public static DialogResult Show(string message, string title)
{
    _msgBox = new MsgBox();
    _msgBox._lblMessage.Text = message;
    _msgBox._lblTitle.Text = title;
    _msgBox.Size = MsgBox.MessageSize(message);

    MsgBox.InitButtons(Buttons.OK);
    //_msgBox.BringToFront();
    _msgBox.ShowDialog();
    return _buttonResult;
}
```

`MsgBox` is the name of the class itself:

```
class MsgBox : Form
```

Comment: You can pass the owner form to the showdialog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to pass the Owner value for your internal message box class

```
public static DialogResult Show(string message, string title, Form owner = null)
{
    _msgBox = new MsgBox();
    _msgBox._lblMessage.Text = message;
    _msgBox._lblTitle.Text = title;
    _msgBox.Size = MsgBox.MessageSize(message);

    MsgBox.InitButtons(Buttons.OK);
    if(owner != null)
        _msgBox.ShowDialog(owner);
    else
        _msgBox.ShowDialog();
    return _buttonResult;
}
```

Using a default parameter you could change the code only where is needed.

After a little research I have found [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816885/form-showdialog-or-form-showdialogthis) that explains a bit this behavior

Comment: I don't know exactly your context, you could try to use a default parameter and change only where it is needed. Updating the answer