# Multiple Showdialog

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I have a main window which calls another window with `ShowDialog()`, lets call it window A. Window A calls another window also with `ShowDialog()`, lets call it window B.

Whenever window B is closed using `Close()`, I want Window A to be shown, not the main window.

How am I supposed to do that? I already tried using `this.Owner`, `this.Focus`, etc. none of them work.

Note: I am using WPF

here is my code from main window:

`WindowsA WA = new WindowsA(); WA.showDialog();`

at `WindowsA`, i call another window `WindowsB`:

`WindowsB WB = new WindowsB(); WB.showDialog();`

from `WindowsB`, I pressed button to close:

`Close();`

Where should I put the owner?

Comment: When you do showDialog for window b, shouldn't you set the owner to Window A, Then anything that windows A opens will go back to window a when it's closed. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2045671/4714970

Comment: Can you post some code? When trying to replicate your problem, my dialog B returns to dialog A as you would expect.

Comment: like @Loocid said when tried to replicate the issue i am also able to return to dialog window A as per your requirement.

Comment: update the question. I put the simple code. @Aequitas, I already try to set the owner to Window A. But still didn't work. 

Loocid, Sachu how many form do you have? I 3 forms, main windows, windows A, windows B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do showDialog for window b, you should set the owner to Window A, Then anything that window A opens will go back to window A when it's closed.

Like this: `WA.ShowDialog(this);`

This will make `this` the owner of WA.

See here for more information on this: www.stackoverflow.com/a/2045671/4714970

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I just figured it out.

Before WA.ShowDialog(), I just set WA.Owner = this;

After that it works.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: you said this didn't work before? Also pretty sure you can do `WA.ShowDialog(this);`

Comment: maybe i forgot to put the 'this' inside the showdialog(). can you just post your answer? i will mark yours as the real answer. thanks